# Copy images from network shared drive to Excelfile

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy multiple images from a network drive to an excel file using each image address to store it in a particular row and cells. They all could be the same size but it should be able to override it whenever I click on the insert image button.

I am currently using a script but it only brings in just one of the images and it can not resize or override.

[enter image description here][1]

The second script, do overrides but only brings in one image and it can not resize.

```
Sub InsertPic()

Dim productImageUrl As String
Dim productImage As Picture     'Declare image picture object
Dim productImageUrlRng As Range 'Declare range object to contain image URL
Dim productImageRng As Range    'Location image will be placed
'Delete any existing pictures:


Set productImageRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:G25") 'Where I want to put the image
Set productImageUrlRng = Range("A2")  'Cell containing image URL
'Set productImageUrlRng = Range("A17:A28")   'Cell containing image URL
productImageUrl = productImageUrlRng

productImageRng.Select
'productImageRng.Delete --Does not delete pictures in range
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Delete     'Delete existing images
Set productImage = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(productImageUrl)

With productImage
    .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
    '.Width = productImageRng.Width
    '.Height = productImageRng.Height
    '.Top = Rows(cl.Row).Top
    '.Left = Columns(cl.Column).Left

Width_HalfSheet = 720
Height_HalfSheet = 330
end_row = 1300
End_Col = 200


End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your codes and by same size, how is the size determined? Constant value?

Comment: Thanks, Raymond, I am getting an error message when pasting the code.

Comment: Please try again to paste your code in the question, i doubt your code is huge so it should be possible. We can help you with the formatting if needed.

Comment: ok, I just did. this code only brings in one image , it does override and the re-sizing seems to be working. it will be great, if it can bring all the images according to their cells and links which are placed by these rows.

Comment: Now there's alot of missing info here - 1) where are the image url stored (whats the range?) 2) exactly where do you want to place the images for each url? (1 column to the right or what?)

Comment: The image url is stored in a network share drive. for example. \\Racp1\data\@EvenSupport\Export-Jpg\CurrentTotal.png. I want to place the image in any cell /column range where I place the URL but in the same sheets. yes, column to the right.